# Unable to change my Date filed using javascript inside my Edit form

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, jquery, sputility

I am working on a sharepoint 2013 on-premises team site. now i want to set a column which is of type date/time to be equal to today date,so i added a script inside the Edit form, then i tried to set the date value using SPUtiltiy, as follow:-

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
alert(today);
SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('OrderDateCustomerApproved_').SetValue(today);
```

but i got this error:-

```
Unable to set date, invalid arguments (requires year, month, and day as integers).

throw "Unable to set date, invalid arguments (requires year, month, and day as integers).";
```

so i tried to do so using pure JavaScript appraoch as follow:-

```
$('select[id^="OrderDateCustomerApproved_"]').val(today);
```

where this did not raise any error, but the field was not populated with today date!!

so can anyone adivce on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My data column is:
[image]

A demo code based on my data column for your reference:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var today = new Date();   
    var dd = today.getDate();   
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;   
    var yyyy = today.getYear();   
    if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
    } 

    today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy; 
    $("input[id^='Date_x0020_Customer_x0020_Approv_']").val(today);
})
</script>
```

Note: you need to change id in the above  code to yours.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following piece of code to set value to Date-time field with SPUtility and jQuery

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$(SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName(internalFieldName).Controls).find('input').first().val((currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear());
```

My Site collection uses `MM/DD/YYYY` format for dates so i'm setting it in that format. You will have to change the format if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar last week. Maybe this will point you in the right direction.

```
<script>
'use strict';
(function() {

    var timeSinceFieldViewCtx = {};

    timeSinceFieldViewCtx.Templates = {};
    timeSinceFieldViewCtx.Templates.Fields = {

        "Time": {  /* Change to your Date Column - Same as below */ 
            "View": timeSinceFieldViewTemplate
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(timeSinceFieldViewCtx);
})();

function timeSinceFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var dateDiff = new Date() - new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Time); /* Change to your Date Column */ 
    var daysDiff = Math.floor(dateDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    return daysDiff;
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-vb-lastCell');

    for( var i =0; i < x.length; ++i ) {

        console.log(x[i].innerText + " Type Of: " + typeof Number(x[i].innerText));

        if (Number(x[i].innerText) > 30 ) { 
            x[i].style.color = 'green';
            x[i].style.fontWeight='normal';
        }
        if (Number(x[i].innerText) > 60 ) { 
            x[i].style.color = 'green';
            x[i].style.fontWeight= 'bold';
        }
    }

}, true);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the code will try it now,, but why my code which looks shorter compared ur code did not work??

Comment: You're trying to achieve something different from what i did.

I think your code only applies to the "New" or "Edit" Form. Do you want to the set the date on a new form or in the list itself?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint adds a format function to a date object, so you can use that to do your formatting as well. And I don't used the ID of the field, I use the title because that makes things easier to read.

```
$("input[title='Date Customer Approved']").val(today.format('MM/dd/yyyy'));
```